# How does refraction work?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW8KuMtVpug&feature=iv&src_vid=CiHN0ZWE5bk&annotation_id=annotation_187211

Start the above video at 8:15.  How does the phase velocity affect the apparent velocity of light in a medium?  From my understanding a phase shift will change the direction of light, but how does this affect the "apparent" velocity?

Comment: see the [Snell's law wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law#Explanation)